# IPv6 basic concepts / best practices

Tags: networking, ipv6

I'm trying to familiarize myself with IPv6.

I found [this guide](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/ipv6-guide/) very useful but still I don't understand some aspects.

**Link-local vs Unique-local**

Reading the above guide I understand that link-local addresses do not cross host boundaries (ie they are not used to communicate between devices).
Unique-local are instead close to the concept of IPv4 local ip addresses.

Is this correct?

**Interface ID**

If I understand correctly, each host is identified by a value that can be calculated from MAC address.
Is this mandatory/best practice?

In IPv4 addresses are not related to MAC address, so for example I can change NIC card on a PC (thus changing its MAC address) and still use the same address.

In addition, IP addresses are usually assigned using some criteria (from a to b to PCs, from x to y to printers, ecc).
This is not mandatory but useful in everyday maintenance.

How can this be done in IPv6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> link-local addresses do not cross host boundaries (ie they are not used to communicate between devices).

No. They *do* cross host boundaries, but they never cross network (or subnet) boundaries.

Link-local addresses are used for packets which previously had to be sent from a null address (e.g. DHCP → DHCPv6), or which were not IP-based at all (e.g. ARP → ICMPv6 NDP). They're also used by routing protocols (RIPng, OSPFv3, Babel…) which previously used a "normal" IP address for messages which are inherently link-scope.

(Technically IPv4 also has link-scope addresses 169.254.0.0/16, but they're optional to have and their usage is much more limited – they're often considered to be mutually exclusive with "normal" addresses. That's not the case in IPv6, where all interfaces normally have a link-local address in addition to everything else.)

However, you may be confusing link scope with "interface-local" or "host" scope addresses, which indeed do not cross host boundaries. Really the only host-scope address you'll ever see is `::1` (loopback).

> Unique-local are instead close to the concept of IPv4 local ip addresses.

Yes, though again their intended usage is slightly different from IPv4. That is, even if you want to use unique-local addresses in your LAN, you should *still* use global addresses alongside them (i.e. each host would have two addresses) – NATing is extremely discouraged, even 1:1 NAT.

Note that in both IPv4 and IPv6, these addresses are considered to have *global* scope. They are only *locally assigned*, but IP doesn't consider them to be fundamentally different from "public Internet" addresses; they're routed in the same way.

> If I understand correctly, each host is identified by a value that can be calculated from MAC address. Is this mandatory/best practice?

No. It's the default option (for networks which have MAC addresses to begin with), but it is not mandatory – IPv6 allows any kind of interface identifier and won't treat them any differently, with minor exceptions.

- Nowadays you'll often see the primary interface ID being replaced by opaque, hash-based interface identifiers according to RFC 7217. It remains stable, but reveals no information externally. (Some operating systems might use a different algorithm but with the same end result.)
- For a long time before that, when most hosts were still using EUI-64 interface identifiers, many of them already implemented RFC 4941 to generate random *temporary* interface identifiers.
- In general, MAC or EUI-64 cannot be mandatory simply because there exist plenty of point-to-point, Layer-3 only tunnel mechanisms (such as PPP) which do not have a Layer-2 address at all.

The algorithm to generate IPv6 addresses from EUI-64 or MAC addresses has been carefully done with regards to the EUI-64 "Local/Global" bit, so that if you simply assign your preferred interface ID by hand (e.g. `<whatever>::123:ab`), it will syntactically look the same as if it were based on a "Locally Administered" EUI-64 address (in this example `02:00:00:00:01:23:00:ab`).

> In addition, IP addresses are usually assigned using some criteria (from a to b to PCs, from x to y to printers, ecc). This is not mandatory but useful in everyday maintenance.

My first suggestion is "use DNS". At work, most of the time I don't type in raw addresses anymore – if I want to connect to a specific printer, I don't start typing `192.`, I start typing `pr-` and the browser offers me a list of printers, not a list of miscellaneous IP addresses.

On larger networks, you'll also want to have multiple VLANs and multiple subnets. Assign subnet ID 1 (e.g. 2001:db8:42:1::/64) to the user VLAN, subnet ID 2 (2001:db8:42:2::/64) to the printer VLAN, and so on.

Most devices won't stop you from assigning IPv6 addresses manually, e.g. you can freely use `2001:db8:42::53` for the DNS server. As mentioned earlier, that's perfectly fine even within the assumptions of EUI-64 assignment – it just maps to a "Locally Administered" EUI-64 address.

(Only few support assigning *just* the interface ID manually while still receiving network prefixes automatically, but hopefully your IPv6 prefix won't change *that* often anyway.)

Comment: Very exhaustive answer, thank you!